# The Loewner order does not have the lattice property

Tags: matrices, order-theory, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

How can we prove that the [Loewner order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loewner_order) does not have the lattice property?

I know that it does not but I couldn't find a reference included the proof. I would appreciate a proof or an address to it.

Comment: The lattice property is a "for all pairs of matrices..." property.  Any pair of matrices that don't satisfy the criterion will act as a counterexample.  What have you done in looking for such a counterexample?

Comment: I have those matrices, what I need is a proof in a mathematical construction, not just a counterexample.

Comment: Can you show the two matrices don't have a greatest lower bound?  Least upper bound?

Comment: consider A=[1,0;01] , B=[2,0;0,1/2] there can be a lot of C have the quality of being greater than them, like C=[2,0;0,1] or C=[3 ,1;1,3/2] since there is not a unique one which is least upper bound respect to loewner ordering , it is not a lattice.

Comment: mostly because there are a lot of matrices that can't be compared by this order.

Answer (score 2):

Theorem 1.1 of Nikolas Stott's [paper](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1612.05664) states:

> Two symmetric  matrices cannot have a greatest lower bound in the Löwner order unless they are comparable in this order.

Partial orders with this property are also called "anti-lattices". The proof can be found in Theorem 6 of Kadison's [paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1951-002-03/S0002-9939-1951-0042064-2/S0002-9939-1951-0042064-2.pdf).